# I don't understand buffered output and cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a really simple program that prints lines using cout and sleeps after each line. All is well and good for about 7 iterations, as the buffer is clearly not flushed at any point. After then, what I assume is only part of the buffer is flushed on every iteration.

I have a few questions about this behaviour:

1. If the buffer is supposedly big enough to fit ~7 lines of output, why is the buffer flushed one line at a time?
2. If this buffer is indeed flushed in this way, what is the advantage to this? Why isn't the whole buffer flushed at once?
3. Is it just a coincidence that the exact same number of characters are flushed to the output as my line length, or is the cout buffer internally flushed based on end-of-line delimiters such as '\n'?

   ```
   int main(){

   for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){

   std::cout << "This is line " << i << '\n';
   Sleep(1000);

   }

   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: It prints about every second, just like you would have expected, for me, with or without '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that the buffer will not be written until it is full.  Probably what happens is that an asynchronous write is started with as little as one output byte.  The empty buffer space is used to receive characters while the asynchronous write is in progress.  When the current write completes, if/when there are additional characters in the buffer, a new asynchronous write is started.  The process would only need to block on writing if the buffer got full.